# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading emod)

Tags: angular, typescript, github, node-modules, angular-components

I'm having an Ang12 project with a custom component in a github repo, and i'm trying to use it in another project but i'm having the following error at runtime: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading emod).
the npm i git@github:.../house-building.git and ng build,serve are working properly, but im having this error when i m using the component from git in the current project:
my-current-project.html:

```
<house-building></house-building>
```

does anyone tried to do this and had this error?

Comment: Try using the Template expression operator '?.'  with emod in code

Comment: as you can  see i dont have an input parameter, the 'emod' is part of the error.

Comment: Please share some code. I guess it's the html template of _house-building_ where you use _emod_.

Comment: i dont have any variable called emod. in the html i have a free text typed in. :(

Comment: check all the associated component, there is a possibility that any of them must have this variable or sub-variable(key of any other object).

Comment: there is no variable called emod in my both projects :( 
i just created a new project house-building, renamed the AppModule to a new one,
HouseBuildingModule which has the following structure:
@NgModule({
declarations: [
MyHouseComponent],
imports: [BrowserModule],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [MyHouseComponent]
})
export class MyHouseModule
and in another project use it:

..
app.module.ts:
..

imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, MyHouseModule]
..
app.component.html:
some test text
<my-house></my-house> The both projects are working fine separately.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same problem. Currently, I have to use the production config to resolve this problem. If you have a perfect resolution, tell me.

Here is my solution:

In `angular.json` set `optimization` to `true`

```json
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": true, // resolve the problem of (reading emod)
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
```